# Seeing a lot of write activity on an Expression Engine website

Tags: expressionengine

I have inherited a website built on Expression Engine which is having a lot of trouble under load. Looking in the server console for the database I am seeing a lot of database writes (300-800/second)

Trying to track down why we are getting so much write activity compared to read activity and seeing things like

```
UPDATE  `exp_snippets` SET  `snippet_contents` = 'some content in here' WHERE  `snippet_name` =  'member_login_form'
```

Why would EE be writing these to the database when no administrative changes are happening and how can I turn this behavior off?

Any other bottlenecks which could be avoided? The site is using an EE ad module so I cannot easily run it through Varnish since the ads need to change on each page load - looking to try and integrate DFP instead so they can be loaded asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of front end operations that trigger INSERT and UPDATE operations.  (Having to do with tracking users, hits, sessions, also generating hashes for forms etc.)

The snippets one tho seems very strange indeed I wouldn't think that snippets would call an UPDATE under normal circumstances.  Perhaps the previous developer did something where the member_login_form (which has dynamic hash in it) is written to a snippet each time it is called? Not sure why you would do it, but there's a guess.

For general speed optimization see:

[Optimizing ExpressionEngine](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/optimization/index.html)

There are a number of configs in the "Extreme Traffic" section that will reduce the number of writes (tho not the snippet one which doesn't seem to be normal behavior).

Comment: I ended up digging through the third party add ons and discovered one called snippetsync which was the culprit. There is a config setting for production mode to essentially turn this off which did the trick